# kernel image error while installing Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: boot, 13.04, system-installation, bios

I downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 to install on my external HDD. I have never worked with a Linux OS before so I'm completely new to this.

After I created a bootable USB flash disk with the ISO image on it, and configured my BIOS to boot from it, it gives an error saying that it could not find the kernel image:

`/isolinux/syslinux.cfg` and then a boot line, I've tried several of the solutions on other forums, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your LiveUSB, follow the following steps :

1. Enter the `isolinux` folder and rename the `isolinux.cfg` file to be `syslinux.cfg`. You may or may not need to rename `isolinux.BIN` to `SYSLINUX.BIN`, but it won't hurt to rename it too.
2. Move up to the top level and rename the `isolinux` folder to be `syslinux`.
3. Try to boot again from the USB.

Source : [USB Installation Media - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/USB%20Installation%20Media)

Comment: In my case it was the opposite. The error said "could not find kernel image /isolinux/isolinux.cfg". I oppened the usbstick folder and renamed the files and folder /syslinux/syslinux.cfg into /isolinux/isolinux.cfg.

Answer (score 1):

- Rename the `isolinux` folder to `syslinux`.And then go into the renamed syslinux folder and change(rename) `isolinux.cfg` file to `syslinux.cfg` which are all inside the USB.
- Then restart and boot from usb.