# Could not find kernel image /isolinux/isolinux.cfg

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, usb, kernel

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 16.0.4 using the Universal USB Installer method for the past 3 hours. I looked up tutorials and searched for answers here but none worked. Any hints?

*Selected sections of Universal USB Installer log*

```
Create folder: E:\uui
Copy to E:\uui\syslinux.cfg
Executing syslinux on E:
Execute: C:\Users\pbgnz\AppData\Local\Temp\nsvB692.tmp\syslinux.exe -maf -d     
/u...
Syslinux Errors 0
Creating Label UUI on E:
'LABEL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Extracting the iso: The progress bar will not move until finished. Please be patient...
```

Then a couple of files are extracted and copied to the usb and the installation is complete. I renamed the files from `isolinux` to `syslinux` as shown in other tutorials.

some answers I tried:

1. [Install Ubuntu 14.04 from bootable USB: Could not find kernel image: /isolinux/isolinux.cfg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709951/install-ubuntu-14-04-from-bootable-usb-could-not-find-kernel-image-isolinux-i)
2. [kernel image error while installing Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382487/kernel-image-error-while-installing-ubuntu-13-10)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I burn the Ubuntu ISO to a CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203601/how-do-i-burn-the-ubuntu-iso-to-a-cd)

Answer (score 0):

I successfully installed Ubuntu on my laptop. I had to "by pass" this issue by burning ubuntu on a dvd. You can probably find tutorials on that.